# Registry read/write in windows 7 using c# code

Tags: c#, windows, permissions, registry

I have a windows C# application which when user runs it i want to save the current time as login time in some registry and also when he close it as logout time.When i tried, it gives me **requested registry access is not allowed** exception.I have tried giving permission to that registry but still getting that exception.Here is the code that i have tried

```
RegistrySecurity rs = new RegistrySecurity();
string currentUserStr = Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Environment.UserName;
rs.AddAccessRule(new RegistryAccessRule(currentUserStr, RegistryRights.WriteKey | RegistryRights.ReadKey | RegistryRights.Delete | RegistryRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));                
RegistryKey Rkey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SYSTEM", true).OpenSubKey("Test", true);
Rkey.SetAccessControl(rs);
```

I also tried using app.manifest to force application run as admin every time but i want to keep that as last option.
So is there any other solution to read/write registry ??

Comment: Have you taken a look at the solutions presented in the MS Support document [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/842795)?

Comment: But how to grant these permissions via c#??

Answer (score 0):

IMO, Your Application needs to run with elated privileges.  Try running Visual Studio as Administrator.

Comment: I want to run the application on the user's system  after i installed on it there is no visual studio there

Answer (score 0):

I just run the code on my machine (windows 7 64 bits) as a `Window Form`. I did not have any problem with it (I could even remove the `AddAccessRule` line).

So the problem is not the code itself. Did you try to change the value in the `registry` *manually* with the same user as you run your code ? From which place (harddisk or network drive or internet..) do you run your code ? I know that running it from a network drive can give problems Let me know then maybe I can help you further

Comment: Ya i changed the registry value manually its working.I am running the code from the same machine only(no network drive or internet is involved).I still cant read/write registry value.

Answer (score 0):

Access to HKLM (and that's what you're doing) requires administrative privileges

@Hitesh: you need to set MANIFESTUAC to "requireAdministrator"

In Visual Studio, this is done in: Project properties -> Linker -> Manifest File and set:

- Enable UAC to Yes,
- UAC Execution Level - requireAdministrator
- UAC Bypass UI - No

P.S. UAC is out there since Windows Vista...